# OpenGL application crashes some times

Tags: c++, opengl, crash, driver

I am working on a OpenGL application in C++ for some months now and never faced this problem before.

Coding in *Visual Studio 2012* I can either run the application inside of the IDE or launch the executable file manually. In both cases I can choose between the debug and the release build. The following issue only appears when I start the release build executable myself. Otherwise everything works fine.

The application crashes sometimes when I add new forms into the scene on the fly. My operating system *Windows 8 64bit* lets me `Debug the program` from the crash dialog which indeed didn't help so much since it is a release build with less debug informations available at runtime, but it at least told me that the application crashes near the draw call `glDrawTriangles()`. There is only one draw call inside a loop in my code.

It drives me crazy that the crash only occurs irregular. Sometimes the application runs quite well for some minutes, sometimes it crashes immediately, and sometimes it runs some seconds. But I think is is important to know that the application only crashes right after new forms are inserted into the scene which I first generate in another thread and second create the OpenGL buffers in the main thread.

Here are the problem details that were shown in the Windows crash dialog. It seems like the driver of my videocard *ATI Radeon 7870* crashes.

> Problem signature:
>     Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
>     Application Name: Application.exe
>     Application Version:  0.0.0.0
>     Application Timestamp:  50f1491a
>     Fault Module Name:  atioglxx.dll
>     Fault Module Version: 6.14.10.11931
>     Fault Module Timestamp: 50650037
>     Exception Code: c0000005
>     Exception Offset: 001108ef
>     OS Version: 6.2.9200.2.0.0.256.27
>     Locale ID:  1031
>     Additional Information 1: 5861
>     Additional Information 2: 5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2
>     Additional Information 3: dac6
>     Additional Information 4: dac6c2650fa14dd558bd9f448e23afd1
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=190175
>
> If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
>     C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

What I've done so far is updating my video card drivers and debugging my application since I notices that the result were not reliable since the crash occurs spontaneously. There are many source files and to be honest I am not sure which is effecting the bug. It might be a file called `terrain.cpp` so I paste the code here.

```
#pragma once

#include "system.h"
#include "debug.h"

#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <future>
using namespace std;
#include <GLEW/glew.h>
#include <SFML/OpenGL.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Image.hpp>
using namespace sf;
#include <GLM/glm.hpp>
#include <GLM/gtc/noise.hpp>
using namespace glm;

#include "settings.h"
#include "camera.h"
#include "form.h"
#include "transform.h"
#include "terrain.h"
#include "shader.h"
#include "movement.h"


typedef detail::tvec3<int> vec3i;

class ComponentTerrain : public Component
{
    void Init()
    {
        auto wld = Global->Add<StorageTerrain>("terrain");

        tasking = false;

        Texture();

        Listeners();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        auto wld = Global->Get<StorageTerrain>("terrain");
        auto stg = Global->Get<StorageSettings>("settings");
        auto cam = Global->Get<StorageCamera>("camera");
        auto cks = Entity->Get<StorageChunk>();

        int Distance = (int)(.5f * stg->Viewdistance / CHUNK_X / 2);
        Debug::Info("Terrain chunk distance " + to_string(Distance));
        for(int X = -Distance; X <= Distance; ++X)
        for(int Z = -Distance; Z <= Distance; ++Z)
        {
            addChunk(X + (int)cam->Position.x / CHUNK_X, 0, Z + (int)cam->Position.z / CHUNK_Z);
        }
        for(auto chunk : wld->chunks)
        {
            auto chk = cks.find(chunk.second);
            float distance = (float)vec3(chunk.first[0] * CHUNK_X - cam->Position.x, chunk.first[1] * CHUNK_Y - cam->Position.y, chunk.first[2] * CHUNK_Z - cam->Position.z).length();
            if(distance > stg->Viewdistance)
                deleteChunk(chunk.first[0], chunk.first[1], chunk.first[2]);
        }

        if(tasking)
        {
            if(task.wait_for(chrono::milliseconds(0)) == future_status::ready)
            {
                tasking = false;
                Data data = task.get();
                Buffers(data);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(auto chunk : cks)
            if(chunk.second->changed)
            {
                tasking = true;
                chunk.second->changed = false;
                task = async(launch::async, &ComponentTerrain::Mesh, this, Data(chunk.first));
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    struct Data
    {
        Data() {}
        Data(unsigned int id) : id(id) {}
        unsigned int id;
        vector<float> Vertices, Normals, Texcoords;
        vector<int> Elements;
    };

    future<Data> task;
    bool tasking;
    Image texture;

    void Listeners()
    {
        Event->Listen("SystemInitialized", [=]{
            auto cam = Global->Get<StorageCamera>("camera");
            cam->Position = vec3(0, CHUNK_Y, 0);
            cam->Angles = vec2(0.75, -0.25);
        });

        Event->Listen("InputBindChunk", [=]{
            addChunk(rand() % 5, 0, rand() % 5);
            addChunk(rand() % 5, 0, rand() % 5);
            addChunk(rand() % 5, 0, rand() % 5);
        });
    }

    unsigned int getChunk(int X, int Y, int Z)
    {
        auto wld = Global->Get<StorageTerrain>("terrain");
        array<int, 3> key = {X, Y, Z};
        auto i = wld->chunks.find(key);
        return (i != wld->chunks.end()) ? i->second : 0;
    }

    int addChunk(int X, int Y, int Z)
    {
        auto wld = Global->Get<StorageTerrain>("terrain");
        auto shd = Global->Get<StorageShader>("shader"); // moved this line

        unsigned int id = getChunk(X, Y, Z);
        if(!id)
        {
            id = Entity->New();
            Entity->Add<StorageChunk>(id);
            auto frm = Entity->Add<StorageForm>(id); // moved this line
            auto tsf = Entity->Add<StorageTransform>(id);

            frm->Program = shd->Program; // moved this line
            tsf->Position = vec3(X * CHUNK_X, Y * CHUNK_Y, Z * CHUNK_Z);

            Generate(id, X, Y, Z);

            array<int, 3> key = {X, Y, Z};
            wld->chunks.insert(make_pair(key, id));
        }
        return id;
    }

    void deleteChunk(int X, int Y, int Z)
    {
        auto wld = Global->Get<StorageTerrain>("terrain");

        unsigned int id = getChunk(X, Y, Z);
        if(id < 1) return;

        array<int, 3> key = {X, Y, Z};
        wld->chunks.erase(key);

        Entity->Delete<StorageChunk>(id);
        Entity->Delete<StorageForm>(id);
        Entity->Delete<StorageTransform>(id);

        // free buffers
    }

    void Generate(unsigned int id, int X, int Y, int Z)
    {
        auto cnk = Entity->Get<StorageChunk>(id);
        cnk->changed = true;

        for(int x = 0; x < CHUNK_X; ++x) {
        const float i = X + (float)x / CHUNK_X;
        for(int z = 0; z < CHUNK_Z; ++z) {
        const float j = Z + (float)z / CHUNK_Z;
                double height_bias = 0.30;
                double height_base = 0.50 * (simplex(0.2f * vec2(i, j)) + 1) / 2;
                double height_fine = 0.20 * (simplex(1.5f * vec2(i, j)) + 1) / 2;
                int height = (int)((height_bias + height_base + height_fine) * CHUNK_Y);
                for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y) cnk->blocks[x][y][z] = true;
        } }
    }

    #define TILES_U 4
    #define TILES_V 4

    Data Mesh(Data data)
    {
        auto cnk = Entity->Get<StorageChunk>(data.id);
        auto *Vertices = &data.Vertices, *Normals = &data.Normals, *Texcoords = &data.Texcoords;
        auto *Elements = &data.Elements;

        const vec2 grid(1.f / TILES_U, 1.f / TILES_V);

        int n = 0;
        for(int X = 0; X < CHUNK_X; ++X)
        for(int Y = 0; Y < CHUNK_Y; ++Y)
        for(int Z = 0; Z < CHUNK_Z; ++Z)
            if(cnk->blocks[X][Y][Z])
            {
                int Tile = Clamp(rand() % 2 + 1, 0, TILES_U * TILES_V - 1);

                for(int dim = 0; dim < 3; ++dim) { int dir = -1; do {
                    vec3i neigh = Shift(dim, vec3i(dir, 0, 0)) + vec3i(X, Y, Z);

                    if(Inside(neigh, vec3i(0), vec3i(CHUNK_X, CHUNK_Y, CHUNK_Z) - 1))
                        if(cnk->blocks[neigh.x][neigh.y][neigh.z])
                            { dir *= -1; continue; }

                    for(float i = 0; i <= 1; ++i)
                    for(float j = 0; j <= 1; ++j)
                    {
                        vec3 vertex = vec3(X, Y, Z) + floatify(Shift(dim, vec3i((dir+1)/2, i, j)));
                        Vertices->push_back(vertex.x); Vertices->push_back(vertex.y); Vertices->push_back(vertex.z);
                    }

                    vec3 normal = normalize(floatify(Shift(dim, vec3i(dir, 0, 0))));
                    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
                    {
                        Normals->push_back(normal.x); Normals->push_back(normal.y); Normals->push_back(normal.z);
                    }

                    vec2 position = (vec2(Tile % TILES_U, Tile / TILES_U) + .25f) * grid;
                    Texcoords->push_back(position.x);            Texcoords->push_back(position.y);
                    Texcoords->push_back(position.x + grid.x/2); Texcoords->push_back(position.y);
                    Texcoords->push_back(position.x);            Texcoords->push_back(position.y + grid.y/2);
                    Texcoords->push_back(position.x + grid.x/2); Texcoords->push_back(position.y + grid.y/2);

                    if(dir == -1) {
                        Elements->push_back(n+0); Elements->push_back(n+1); Elements->push_back(n+2);
                        Elements->push_back(n+1); Elements->push_back(n+3); Elements->push_back(n+2);
                    } else {
                        Elements->push_back(n+0); Elements->push_back(n+2); Elements->push_back(n+1);
                        Elements->push_back(n+1); Elements->push_back(n+2); Elements->push_back(n+3);
                    }
                    n += 4;

                dir *= -1; } while(dir > 0); }
            }

        return data;
    }

    void Buffers(Data data)
    {
        auto frm = Entity->Get<StorageForm>(data.id);

        glGenBuffers(1, &frm->Positions);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, frm->Positions);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data.Vertices.size() * sizeof(float), &(data.Vertices[0]), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glGenBuffers(1, &frm->Normals);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, frm->Normals);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data.Normals.size() * sizeof(float), &(data.Normals[0]), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glGenBuffers(1, &frm->Texcoords);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, frm->Texcoords);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, data.Texcoords.size() * sizeof(float), &(data.Texcoords[0]), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glGenBuffers(1, &frm->Elements);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, frm->Elements);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, data.Elements.size() * sizeof(int), &data.Elements[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glGenTextures(1, &frm->Texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, frm->Texture);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texture.getSize().x, texture.getSize().y, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.getPixelsPtr());
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }

    void Texture()
    {
        Image image;
        bool result = image.loadFromFile("forms/textures/terrain.png");
        if(!result){ Debug::Fail("Terrain texture loading fail"); return; }

        Vector2u size = Vector2u(image.getSize().x / TILES_U, image.getSize().y / TILES_V);
        texture.create(image.getSize().x * 2, image.getSize().y * 2, Color());
        for(int u = 0; u < TILES_U; ++u)
        for(int v = 0; v < TILES_V; ++v)
        {
            Image tile, quarter;
            tile.create(size.x, size.y, Color());
            tile.copy(image, 0, 0, IntRect(size.x * u, size.y * v, size.x, size.y), true);
            quarter.create(size.x, size.y, Color());
            quarter.copy(tile, 0,          0,          IntRect(size.x / 2, size.y / 2, size.x / 2, size.y / 2), true);
            quarter.copy(tile, size.x / 2, 0,          IntRect(0,          size.y / 2, size.x / 2, size.y / 2), true);
            quarter.copy(tile, 0,          size.y / 2, IntRect(size.x / 2, 0,          size.x / 2, size.y / 2), true);
            quarter.copy(tile, size.x / 2, size.y / 2, IntRect(0,          0,          size.x / 2, size.y / 2), true);
            texture.copy(quarter, (u * 2    ) * size.x, (v * 2    ) * size.y, IntRect(0, 0, 0, 0), true);
            texture.copy(quarter, (u * 2 + 1) * size.x, (v * 2    ) * size.y, IntRect(0, 0, 0, 0), true);
            texture.copy(quarter, (u * 2    ) * size.x, (v * 2 + 1) * size.y, IntRect(0, 0, 0, 0), true);
            texture.copy(quarter, (u * 2 + 1) * size.x, (v * 2 + 1) * size.y, IntRect(0, 0, 0, 0), true);
        }
    }

    template <typename T>
    inline T Clamp(T Value, T Min, T Max)
    {
        if(Value < Min) return Min;
        if(Value > Max) return Max;
        return Value;
    }

    bool Inside(vec3i Position, vec3i Min, vec3i Max)
    {
        if(Position.x < Min.x || Position.y < Min.y || Position.z < Min.z) return false;
        if(Position.x > Max.x || Position.y > Max.y || Position.z > Max.z) return false;
        return true;
    }

    inline vec3i Shift(int Dimension, vec3i Vector)
    {
        if      (Dimension % 3 == 1) return vec3i(Vector.z, Vector.x, Vector.y);
        else if (Dimension % 3 == 2) return vec3i(Vector.y, Vector.z, Vector.x);
        else                         return Vector;
    }

    vec3 floatify(vec3i Value)
    {
        return vec3(Value.x, Value.y, Value.z);
    }
};
```

However, you can find the [whole code on Github](https://github.com/ComputerGame/GraphicsApplication/tree/terrain/Application).

Do you have any idea what could cause the crash or how to find the bug? Please let me know if you need more information and of which kind.

Thanks to @doomster I could find and fix the bug now.

The renderer component loops over a vector of forms to draw them. The asynchronous thread added new forms to that vector but their buffers were created later in the main thread after the generated vertices were returned. That means that drawing and form adding ran in parallel. The crash occurred when the renderer tried to render a form without any created buffers yet.

I inserted comments the code above to highlight the three lines I moved from `addChunk()` to `Buffers()` for fixing the issue. I sill do not know why only the release build executable crashed but that doesn't really matter any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things I would verify here:

- You are using a `future<T>`. I'm not sure, but if it runs in a different thread, that could have a negative impact on OpenGL which I have heard can behave sensitive to multithreaded use. Treat this as a rumour though, I'm not really sure about it, but trying to convert to single-threaded code is worth an attempt.
- You can activate debug symbols in a release build, too. This should at least give you a usable backtrace when the crash happens. Actually, VS's Debug/Release settings are just default settings but without intrinsic meaning, so you can modify the Debug settings in steps until it matches the Release settings. That should give you a variant that fails while still being usable in a debugger.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did that and I could solve the problem! So I finally fixed the issue after five hours I spent last night trying to do so!

Comment: Indeed OpenGL and multithreading is a sensitive subject. Technically it's no problem to do this, but in practice it means a lot of bookkeeping. It can be summarized as this: A OpenGL context can be active in only one thread at a time. Migrating a context from one thread to another requires to unbind the other context by the first thread first. If you have a thread pool, you can create a context for each thread and make them share their resources, but some OpenGL objects (FBOs, VAOs) don't share.

Comment: The easiest and best solution is, in fact, to keep all OpenGL operations to one single thread. The only exception is, if you have several windows and want them to swap all their buffer synchronized. The usual SwapBuffers call blocks until the swap happened, so the only way is to have a thread and context for each window and have them all call SwapBuffers synchronously.